# Getting clang-format to format args/params conditionally or with preference

Tags: clang-format

I'm new to using clang-format (version 6.0.0) and was wondering how to get sort of preferential alignment. Specifically I would like the following.

If params can fit on a single line, do that:

```
int f( int a, int b, int c) {
```

If not, then try to stack params (bin packing):

```
int f( int a,
       int b,
       int c) {
```

If one or more of the stacked parameters still do not fit in specified column boundary, just break to new line.

```
int f(
    int a, int b, int c) {
```

So far I've only figured out how to get one of these formats but not how to get multiple in this sort of preferred priority order. It seems I must stick to Align or AlwaysBreak. Is there any way to get the sort of param ordering specified here?

Here is my .clang-format

```
Language: Cpp                                                                                                                       
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align                                                     
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false                                                                            
BinPackParameters: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements as expressed above are kind-of contradictory. Consider the last case ("If one or more of the stacked parameters still do not fit in specified column boundary, just break to new line"). If a "stacked" parameter doesn't fit in the column boundary, then "just break to new line" will certainly not fit on a single line because that line contains even more than just the really long stacked parameter.

Using `clang-format` 6.0.0, I tried reproducing your issue using the following input file:

```
// If params can fit on a single line, do that
int f( int a, int b, int c)
{
    return do_something();
}

// If not, then try to stack params (bin packing)
int g( int aLongerName, int bLongerName, int cLongerName, int dLongerName, int eLongerName)
{
    return do_something();
}

// If one or more of the stacked parameters still do not fit in the
// specified column boundary, just break to new line
int g( int aLongerName, int bLongerName, int cReaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaallyLongName)
{
    return do_something();
}
```

Then, using the `.clang-format` file you provide, the output is:

```
// If params can fit on a single line, do that:
int f(int a, int b, int c) { return do_something(); }

// If not, then try to stack params (bin packing)
int g(int aLongerName,
      int bLongerName,
      int cLongerName,
      int dLongerName,
      int eLongerName) {
  return do_something();
}

// If one or more of the stacked parameters still do not fit in the
// specified column boundary, just break to new line
int g(
    int aLongerName,
    int bLongerName,
    int cReaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaallyLongName) {
  return do_something();
}
```

This actually seems very close to what you're asking for, except for the last case splitting parameters onto several lines, which is necessary given the length of the parameters. If this isn't what you want, can you please provide a better explanation/example of how you want this to look?